# Is there a way to make an editbox in an overlaped childwindow editable?

Tags: c++, winapi, c++11, mfc

The last two days I worked on my little GUI. I'm new in the C++ and WINAPI world and want to learn some basic things about the WINAPI.

Currently I created a childWindow with the WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW and WS_CHILD style in my parent Window and added a button and an editbox. I subclassed the CALLBACK function for my buttons and editbox so that they have an own callback function. The Buttons works currently fine but the editbox not. I can't click inside the editbox and edit the text.

This is the way I created my Windows:

1. Create a normal parent/main Window
2. Create a childwindow with WS_CHILD and WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW style
3. Add an editbox and a button with WS_CHILD style to the childwindow

Here a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

If I remove the WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW or the WS_CHILD style from the childwindow the editbox works. But then the childwindow has no "windowborder" or is not inside the parentwindow anymore.

After searching in the internet I found out that MDI Windows could solve this problem.

Now my final question is if it's absolutely not possible to create an childwindow with the WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW style and add there editboxes and other control elements? Is the MDI Window the only way or are there maybe some styles/settings I could use to get the editbox working?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do by making an "overlapped child window"? Are you trying to make a document window? Then yes, you will need to either use MDI or some other similar technology. You can't have an overlapped child window; that's mixing two different window types (top-level and child).

Comment: I suggest thoroughly reading about [Window Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx). The [Window Overviews](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468924.aspx) are also mandatory reading. TL;DR: Use `WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER`.

Comment: Thx a lot. "Window Styles. The Window Overviews" this both helps me a lot.... i was a bit lost on the MSDN site.. seems didn't find the right sites i needed :S The WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER style makes no TitleBar. But suing the styles WS_CHILD | WS_POPUPWINDOW I found an alternative. Its not inside the overlaped window anymore but its a child popup window and editbox works :) Else i would have to use MDI.

Comment: Somehow i cant edit my comment anymore... so I mean only WS_POPUPWINDOW .. without WS_CHILD